# Special character not correctly visible on Windows deployment

Tags: java, html, utf-8

I have J2EE web application that is deployed on tomcat on windows and ubuntu.

There is a text "Raphaël", that I am reading from local file(csv) system, that is coming correctly on ubuntu browsers, but it is coming as "RaphaÃ«l" on windows browsers.

I am using in Jsp

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Also I have tried following meta tags also, but they didn't work.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

What could be the problem here?

CSV reading code is

```
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
final List<String[]> licenses =  reader.readAll();
```

Comment: Can you post the code that reads the csv file?

Comment: @AntonK. I have added csv reader code in the question

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have UTF-8 encoding in both CSV file and JVM.

For JVM setting use :

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

To check file encoding on linux use:

```
file --mime-encoding file.name
```

For setting encoding on JSP page use:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

If that does not help add a filter in order to have proper encoding for all responses:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
throws ServletException
{
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: None of these are working. I have tried `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in tomcat connector and also tried with Filter. Also saved csv file with utf-8 encoding

Comment: Open the file, read the string and log it to the console in order to see if the encoding is right in that part.

Answer (score 0):

Set your JSP contentType as UTF-8

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read the file using correct encoding. The way you read the file depends on the default encoding of J2EE server's JVM, which can be anything. My suggestion is to do something like this:

```
final FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(file);
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
```

**and** also set UTF-8 encoding in the JSP as Joseph has written above:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```